# How to have a regulated 5v DC voltage from a 15-25v DC, 0.5A - Electric Motor Generator?

Tags: generator, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to make a hand generator to charge a phone. I have a set-up that can create 15-25v from a DC electric motor. I would like to have a regular output of 5v. I have done some research and found that I could use an IC 7805 and a couple of capacitors on both the input and output to the IC. However, I am unsure whether this will create a stable, 5v output as the hand generator is very variable and does not create a stable output voltage.

Could you please give me some advice on what semiconductors and capacitors I would need to create a stable output voltage?

Comment: The datasheet should state which capacitors you need. Your greater hurdle would be how to get rid of the heat. \$(25V - 5V) * 0.5A = 10W\$ is no joke.

Comment: Just use a buck converter. A linear regulator would result in a huge power loss and turning your generator would be really hard

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will use the buck converter.